# how to dynamically set Notify Filter for file system watcher in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, filter, filesystemwatcher, notify

I have values being pulled from a database that specify if the user has selected a specific notify filter to be associated with the file system watcher. My question is if the user has specified multiple notify filters how to assign that to the watcher?

I understand the format of how the notify filter should be supplied I.E

`fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName OR NotifyFilters.CreationTime OR ......`

the problem is that i can assign each individual notify filter to the watcher using an if statement checking if the user has specified a certain notify filter and keep checking but that just sets the notify filter to the last checked value.

Using `fsw.Notifyfilter += Notifyfilters.FileName` does not work

Please Help

Comment: Just keep repeating assignments that OR the single option.  Start with 0.  Then fsw.NotifyFilter = fsw.NotifyFilter Or option repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,  so you want something like this right?

```
If condition Then
  fsw.NotifyFilter = (fsw.NotifyFilter Or NotifyFilters.FileName)
Else If condition2 Then
  fsw.NotifyFilter = (fsw.NotifyFilter Or NotifyFilters.CreationTime)
...
End If
```

This is basically the equivalent of doing your OR'ing all at once, except broken down into multiple steps.